# How to set different widths for bars in barchart

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, flot

I am using `flot` library to build a barchart. I need to set different widths for each bar. I am quite new to `flot` and javascript in general, so I wouldn't want to hack my way around that.

Is there a clean way to do that ?

Comment: Try it yourself first, then ask specific questions here.

Comment: The question seems quite specific and totally understandable for a newbie to not be able to find his way around that as in most flot examples such a case is not covered. Feel free to prove me wrong.

Comment: Different bar widths in a single data series is not possible without changing the internal code of the plugin. What you can do is split your data series into multiple series, one per needed bar width.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this by editting the style properties of canvas with class name flot-base. Add an extra CSS class to this class property in the HTML, or do it dynamically with Javascript. To do this you can [add it to the classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), edit the style properties or use the [jquery addClass method](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/).

For example, when your flot code has loaded into the DOM, you can access the correct canvas with:

```
var myFlot = document.querySelector('.flot-base');
myFlot.style.display.width = '1200px';
myFlot.style.display.height = '500px';
// alternative: myFlot.classList.add('cssClassWithCorrectDimensions');
```

Edit: it's possible that I misunderstood your question, and you meant the individual bars in a barchart. In which case: I'm sorry. :p

I hope this helped you. :-)

Comment: Can you give me some insight of your idea in implementing that using javascript ?

Comment: Changing the style of the canvas does nothing for the individual bars inside the chart.

Comment: I edited my original post. Does this help you out some more?

Comment: Indeed I  meant that I need every individual bar to have different width . Some google research shown that these charts are "Marimekko" graphs and flot.js library does not support a plugin for that .